# Is HttpWebRequest the proper way to make soap request?

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I've used a a few service references in vb.net/vs 2010, but this was the first one that both required a certificate and a custom soap header. I was given a WSDL and request xml which I tested successfully in soapUI 3.5. After creating a service reference in vb.net I could not figure out how to add a custom soap header.

I saw many examples that implement `IClientMessageInspector`, but could not get any of them to work for one reason or another. Most had to do with my lack of understanding of the Implements keyword, but there was also an issue with endpoint behaviors. I already use an endpoint behavior for the certificate and could not get two endpoint behaviors to work on a single endpoint.

I switched to HttpWebRequest, but can't get it to work either. The code runs, but I get a similar error from the server. The error is `"Remote server returned an error:(500) Internal Server Error".` I used Fiddler to see the actual request and response, and the response is from their data power server is, `"TID:247456978.Catastrophic Error. Please call IAS Datapower Support [ 'dp:reject' executed - Unable to find metadata for 'long_url' ]".` The developer's response is that their system is running fine, so the problem is mine. I agree because I can get a valid response using soapUI.

So the question is, what am I doing wrong. Does the code below even look right. Am I on the right track or should I toss this attempt and look for another solution to making a soap request without using a service reference.

```
   Public Shared Sub TryIt()
    Try
        Dim sSoapEnv As String = "<soap:Envelope>
           {Rest of soap envelope here}"
        sSoapEnv &= "</soap:Envelope>"
        'MsgBox(sSoapEnv)
        ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://yada.yada.yada.com:443/restofurl")

        Dim cert As New X509Certificate2 
        cert.Import("T:\fullpathtocert\fw.hdnipa.com.p12", "cert_password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet)

        Dim cred As New NetworkCredential("gdebacke.fmcdmn.local", "domain_password")
        request.Credentials = cred 
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)


        ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST"
        ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        Dim postData As String = sSoapEnv
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        ' Get the request stream.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        ' Write the data to the request stream.

        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        ' Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close()
        ' Get the response.
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.                   
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        ' Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: which certificate and soap header needs your request?

Comment: I think you are a long way off the trail. When building SOAP clients in .NET, you should stick to WCF, unless you have a really good reason not to.  It sounds like you tried, but got stuck on implementing multiple endpoint behaviors on a single endpoint.  You ought to focus on solving *that* problem. Maybe you need to ask a new question describing that situation.

Comment: Here's a hint: you probably don't need a comment on every line. If your readers don't know that `dataStream.Close()` closes the stream, then they're in big trouble!

Comment: John,The comments on every line are from the sample. Sorry I didn't take the time to remove them

Comment: Cheeso, Are you saying this will not work AT ALL. I realize sticking with WFC is preferred, but after posting 2 questions on asp.net and vb.net specific sights and getting NO responses I gave up after more than a week. I need to get this going and if I can do it without WFC, I don't really care. Will this work is the question.

Comment: Mr. I don't understand your question. There is a single soap header which is enclosed in <soap:Header></soap:Header>. There is also a single p12 cert which gets added.

Comment: WCF is the right way to do it, and [so] is the right place to ask your questions.

Comment: Will this work is the question. That is the question I posted and that is the question I was hoping to get an answer to. If the answer is no, then I will seek out another solution. That solution may be to revisit WFC. It may be to switch to Java. It may be to farm this out to someone who can do it and get it up and running quicker than I can.

Comment: I was able to output the soupUI envelope Fiddler and it has a <wsse:Security> block in the header which my output does not. So my issue is definitely a problem with the cert. My old WCF script is also lacking any security block in the header, so the endpoint behavior I have set up for the cert is not correct as well.

Comment: I passed the code off to the programmer who supplied me with the WSDL and he was able to run this code without the cert (he does not need it on his side). So if you need custom soap headers and have trouble with the odd way that Microsoft decided to do it with the .Net Service Reference, this code works! Once we figure out the issue with the cert I will post the solution.

Comment: I should add that I made some changes to this code before I gave it to the programmer. Properties of the request object like Host, Useragent, ContentType, and Accept are now different. This did not help me to make it work, but it may have help him. I don't know.